# Gratis SMS gateway

Tags: windows, java, sms

I need an SMS gateway software like [Ozeki NG](http://ozekisms.com/). I am testing this product right now, but before investing in a commercial product I would like to map the free alternatives.

[Kannel](http://www.kannel.org/) was recommended for me, but it is Linux-based that makes the configuration more difficult.

Do you know any good opensource alternative to Ozeki NG for Windows?

Basic functions:

- two-way SMS messaging (sending/receiving)
- capacity: about 1500-2000 SMS / day

Bonus functions:

- email-to-SMS
- SMS sending from databases (primarily from MySQL)
- some APIs (primarily Java API) would be also useful for me.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Currently its quite unclear what you are looking for if someone doesn't know Ozeki NG or Kannel. Please describe the features you want in your question. (You can [edit](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/posts/18567/edit) it for this) That way its easier to be found and you will get better answers targeted on your need.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use the following server side alternatives:
```

- http://wammu.eu/gammu/ - Gammu (fork of Gnokii)
- http://smstools3.kekekasvi.com/ - SMS Server Tools

  - https://metacpan.org/pod/GSM::SMS - GSM::SMS (includes messaging
    daemon)

  For GUI you can use the following software:
- http://playsms.org/ - PlaySMS (works with Kannel, Gammu)

  - http://kalkun.sourceforge.net/ - Kalkun (works with Gammu)
- http://wammu.eu/wammu/ - Wammu (GUI to Gammu SMSD)